# How to catch change event for a cell containing a formula

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am currently working on an Excel 2007 plugin and need to monitor a range of cell from a worksheet.
I managed to implement the Change event for the worksheet and if the change takes places in the range of cells I am interested I am doing some business logic.
My problem is that in the range of cell I have a few cells that get their values using a formula from other cells outside my "interest range".
If one of the cells containing the formula change, the Change event is not triggered.

How can I catch the change event even for the cells containing formulas?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
Function GetPrecedents(rInput As Range) As Range
' Returns combined range of all precedents of the input range.
Dim rCell As Range, rPrec As Range, rOutput As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rCell In rInput
        For Each rPrec In rCell.DirectPrecedents
            If Not rPrec Is Nothing Then
                If rOutput Is Nothing Then
                    Set rOutput = rPrec
                Else
                    Set rOutput = Union(rOutput, rPrec)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set GetPrecedents = rOutput

End Function
```

Now of course, if you really want to get clever, you need to make this recursive to consider the precedents of the precedents of the precedents... But I don't have time.

Comment: this looks interesting... I'll try it to see how it will handle my job. Thanks!

Comment: after translating the code to C# and understanding that I actually need a try/catch block when trying to access the DirectPrecedents as apparently there is no way to check if there are any [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vsto/thread/8A500E3C-4EC1-49A1-BF04-8486BC951BEF) I managed to get my desired behavior. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: another question if possible: the above code is not working in case I add a formula referencing another Sheet... any idea why and how I could solve it? Thank you!

Comment: I noticed in the MSDN documentation that DirectPrecedents works only with the current active worksheet and can't track remote references. However, even Precedents doesn't seem to work... :|

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event.

It is triggered, whenever the worksheet is recalculated, so it will catch a formula induced change of any cell in your worksheet.

Comment: I don't see the Calculate event for the worksheet. I am using VSTO (not VBA addin for which I read about this event) and I can only see the Calculate method for the worksheet... Am I missing something and don't realize it? Thank you!

Comment: ok... found it eventually using something like `((Excel.DocEvents_Event)workSheet).Calculate += new Excel.DocEvents_CalculateEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Calculate);` but I see that the code for the event doesn't have any arguments. So my question now is how do I understand which cell(s) where calculated?

Comment: The `Application.Caller` object would provide you with that information - at least under VBA it would. Oh, scratch that, you would then also need the precedents informations from Vinny ;)